# Do Blu-ray drives have an RID?

Tags: blu-ray, forensics

CDs and DVDs have a unique number identifying the drive that writes them named a RID (**R**ecorder **ID**entification).

Does a Blu-ray, a newer form of optic-media, also have an RID?

---

*This is a follow up to [Where is the serial number of the DVD/CD writer stored on the CD?](https://superuser.com/q/217890/11116)*

Answer (score 19):

[Yes](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/258727447_Possibilities_of_the_forensic_investigation_of_CD_DVD_and_Blu-ray_Disc):

> it is possible to identify the drive that was used for burning in the Blu-ray Disc standard. In a fixed area on the BD is the Disc Definition Structure Field (DDS) for identifying the burning hardware. The size is variable, but may not exceed 2048 bytes for storing manufacturer, model and the serial number. At rewritable BD-REs, the identifier is located in the Physical Access Control Field (PAC). Both fields are located outside the data area of the optical medium.

According to the same paper, apparently one doesn't need exotic drives or software to read that info for BluRays (unlike for DVDs and even more so for CDs). They report that "Nero Disc Info" can read the data, at least the PAC for BD-RE (rewritable).  (This is not too surprising, considering that their citation for the previous quote is "Blu-ray Disc Association: Rewritable Blu-ray Disc (BD-RE) Multi-Media Command Set Description. White paper (2004), S. 37", which suggests standard MMC commands can read that.)

Also, a rewritable (BD-RE) disc apparently permanently stores all the drives that wrote it (even after erasing the disc "in full")!

[image]

They report no new entries added though if the drive was used before on that disc, so the order of the PAC entries only reflects first write order by a drive. (The did like 10 writes with those 4 drives.)